# Why does the transmission of a material depend on its wavelength?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chemistry

my question is pretty much in the title 'Why does the transmission of a material depend on its wavelength?' I know it's to do with electrodynamics and solid-state physics. I was just hoping someone could drop a 'general' answer to do with electrodynamics and solid-state physics or links to interesting articles and papers (not too complex). I am doing spectrophotometry on thin films and would just like any bits of information or research just to help me with some basic understanding and so I can understand/analyse my work better.

Thank you for any information/help it is much appreciated.

Comment: Reflection index is dependent on the frequency of light which causes a prism to dissolve colors from an incident white light. Look up the key word " reflection index dispersion" in google for references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a transparent material, it is possible for a particular type of molecular bond in that material to be strongly excited by one particular wavelength of light if the characteristic bond energy closely matches the energy content of the photons with that wavelength. This will cause the otherwise transparent material to block the passage of those wavelengths of light.

In lots of molecules, there are bonds that can be excited by infrared light, and IR light shining through them will have specific frequencies knocked out of its spectrum, producing an *IR absorption spectrum* which is a unique "fingerprint" for that certain type of molecule. This allows unknown chemical substances to be readily identified by comparing their IR absorption spectra against a database containing thousands of different spectra from known samples of chemical compounds.